# Use custom configuration file for ansible provisioner

Tags: packer

I am trying to provision a machine built with `packer`, using its `ansible` provisioner;

Provisioning fails to find some roles which I have set in my custom `ansible.cfg` file as follows:

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = yaml
retry_files_enabled = False
vault_password_file = .vault
roles_path = ./roles
```

Packer [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html) does not indicate a way of passing location to custom `ansible.cfg` file;

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be solved using [ansible environmental vars](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html#ansible_env_vars)

e.g.

```
  "provisioners": [
    {
    "type": "ansible",
    "playbook_file": "ansible/playbooks/install.yml",
    "ansible_env_vars": [ "ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=ansible/roles", "ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=ansible/.vault" ]
   },
```

Comment: yep, it is just that I need 2 more days for that ... :)

Comment: I want to notice that using ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH, if you add a relative path, it will be from where you are currently executing packer, not where the playbook is neither the packer json file.

Answer (score 8):

You could use packer's env vars to set the ansible.cfg location instead of moving all the configurations to packer.

```
"provisioners": [
    {
    "type": "ansible",
    "playbook_file": "ansible/playbooks/install.yml",
    "ansible_env_vars": [ "ANSIBLE_CONFIG=ansible/ansible.cfg" ]
   }
]
```

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file